# Mechanical advantage

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Would the mechanical advantage or behavior of a second class lever change if the load was "bolted" underneath the lever arm as opposed to the classical diagram of the load resting on top?

I'm just curious if you would approach any problem of this nature a different way, not sure if the action of the fulcrum remains the same.
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter if the load is secured underneath, in line, or on top of the lever. If the center of mass of the load is the same distance from the fulcrum, and the effort is the same distance from the fulcrum, the leverage will be the same.

Comment: Thank you Adrian!